# Pagination not working as expected in Android recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, pagination, notifydatasetchanged

I am facing an issue in implementing pagination behavior in android.

Issue Faced:
When I add the new list of items are added to the recyclerview it is scrolling to the top item.

I want to avoid the recyclerview scrolling to the top and have to add the new list of items.

My current code is as below:

```
with(recyclerview) {
                    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(MainApplication.appContext).apply {
                        bookingList.addAll(it.bookings as ArrayList<Upcoming>)
                        list = it
                        if (Adapter == null) {
                                adapter = Adapter(bookingList)
                                previouSize = it.bookings.size
                            }
                        } else {
                            val recyclerViewState =
                                recyclerview.layoutManager?.onSaveInstanceState()
                            adapter?.updateData(bookingList)
                            if (viewModel.pageNo > 1) {
                                adapter?.notifyItemRangeInserted(previouSize?.minus(1)!!, previouSize?.plus(it.size)!!)
                                previouSize = adapter?.itemCount
                            } else {
                                adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()

                            }
                            recyclerview.layoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState)
                        }
                    }
```

UpdateData function:

```
fun updateData(upcoming: List<Upcoming>?) {
        list = upcoming!!
    }
```

I have tried with `notifyDatasetChanged`, `notifyItemRangeInserted`, `notifyItemRangeChanged`, `notifyItemInserted`, `notifyItemChanged` nothing is working. I have tried removing `onSaveInstanceState` on `onRestoreInstanceState` also.

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: try using jetpack pagination library - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/

Comment: @PavanVarma came to know about the library after posting the question. Exploring about that now.